# Implementing accuracy for triplet loss in keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, evaluation, loss-function

I want to implement an accuracy function for a triplet loss network so that I know, how does the algorithm works during the training. So far I have tried something, but I'm not sure whether it actually can work and also I have troubles implementing it in keras. My idea was to compare the predicted anchor-positive and anchor-negative distances (in `y_pred`), so that the positive distance should be low enough and the negative one large enough:

```
def accuracy(_, y_pred):
    pos_treshold = 0.4
    neg_treshold = 0.6
    return K.mean(y_pred[0] < pos_treshold and y_pred[1] > neg_treshold)
```

The problem with this is that I couldn't figure out how to implement this `and` condition in keras.

Then I tried to find something on this topic of accuracy for triplet loss. One way of doing it is to define the accuracy as a proportion of the number of triplets in which the predicted distance between the anchor image and the positive image is less than the one between the anchor image and the negative image. With this I have even bigger problems in implementing it in keras.

I tried this (although I don't know whether it does what I described):

```
K.mean(y_pred[0] < y_pred[1])
```

which gives me accuracy around 0.5 all the time (probably some random stuff). So still I don't know whether the model is bad or the accuracy function is bad.

So my question is how to implement any reasonable accuracy function in keras? Whether it would be one of these two I don't really care.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to implement a metric which represents the accuracy of your net, but you are returning continuous values, therefore you cannot use keras' built ins? And this accuracy should tell what is the average number of elements in `y_pred[0]<pos_treshold and y_pred[1] > neg_treshold`? I don't know what architecture you are using, could you give a brief explanation of the shape of your outputs

Comment: @gionni It's a normal triple loss architecture, where triplets (anchor, positive, negative) are taken as input during the training, a feature vector is computed for each of them and two distances are the output stored in `y_pred`: distance between anchor and positive image and distance between anchor and negative image. It's trained so that anchor-positive distance is close to `0` and anchor negative distance is close to `1`. I need some accuracy so that I know how the training is doing (the ones in the question were just my not working attempts).

Comment: What about printing out the average anchor-positive distance and the average anchor-negative distance?

Answer (score 0):

That's what I use (condition y_pred[0] < y_pred[1]), while taking into account the batch dimension. Note that I'm not using a `mean`, so that it would support sample-weight.

```
def triplet_accuracy(_, y_pred):
    '''
        Input:  y_pred shape is (batch_size, 2)
                [pos, neg]
        Output: shape (batch_size, 1)
                loss[i] = 1 if y_pred[i, 0] < y_pred[i, 1] else 0
    '''

    subtraction = K.constant([-1, 1], shape=(2, 1))
    diff =  K.dot(y_pred, subtraction)
    loss = K.maximum(K.sign(diff), K.constant(0))

    return loss
```